# How to prove that extended euclidean algorithm has time complexity $log(max(m,n))$?

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-algorithm

I tried to search on internet and also thought by myself but was unsuccessful.
Intuitively i think it should be O(max(m,n)).
can someone give easy explanation since i am beginner in algorithms.

Comment: The extended algorithm has the same complexity as the standard one (the steps are just "heavier"). The logarithmic bound is proven by the fact that the Fibonacci numbers constitute the worst case.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you explain the proof in simple words ? i am beginner in algorithms

Comment: What do you know about the Fibonacci numbers ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Just the recurrence relation .I don't have any idea how they are used to prove complexity in computer science

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

In the Euclidean algorithm, the decay of the variables is obtained by the division of the largest by the smallest, using $a=bq+r$ i.e. $r=a-bq$, then swapping $a,b\to b,r$, as long as $q>0$. It is clear that the worst case occurs when the quotient $q$ is the smallest possible, which is $1$, on every iteration, so that the iterations are in fact

$$a,b\to b,a-b.$$

If you reverse this assignment, you get

$$a,b\to a+b,b$$

and you obtain the recurrence relation that defines the Fibonacci sequence.

Hence the longest decay is achieved when the initial numbers are two successive Fibonacci, let $F_n,F_{n-1}$, and the complexity is $O(n)$ as it takes $n$ step to reach $F_1=F_0=1$.

Now we know that $F_n=O(\phi^n)$ so that $$\log(F_n)=O(n).$$